# Why does phase conjugation not result in superposition?

Tags: optics

I'm reading about phase conjugations in optics [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Phase_conjugation) while [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Optische_Phasenkonjugation) is more extensive but it's in German. Nevertheless, the image might visualize it quite well:

[image]

I wonder why such a reflected phase conjugated wave, which travels back to its source (?!) doesn't add to the impinging wave up to a superposition wave?
Another question though it is quite fundamental: In which way does the phase describe the direction, respectively angle of reflection, here?

PS: Top left reads as "Original and result image", top right is a "phase conjugating mirror", bottom right is "regular mirror" and bottom left is "double distorted image".
"Verzerrt" means distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outgoing (phase conjugated) wave *will* interact with the incoming wave (from the bottle; the interaction isn't visible in the picture though, just for clarity I guess). Just as two opposite traveling pulses on a rope will interact. When the pulses on the rope have traveled "through" one another, they will continue their (undisturbed) motion. The waves in your example are not pulses but long structures. Only the outcoming wave will reach your eye though (undisturbed like each of the two pulses on the rope). After it has interacted with the incoming wave (which goes into the mirror).

In the first image, you see only the on-the-mirror-impinging-bottle-distorted wave. in the second picture, you see only the wave that emerges from the mirror. These two do superimpose. That is, in the classical picture of light. This doesn't mean that there is no energy traveling in between though (even though the two waves might superimpose in such a way that the result is zero).

Comment: I would add that photons do not interact (to first order; second order is down by 1/c^2) , so the only time the waves "interact" is when you force an imaging plane.  Since these two wavefronts are moving in opposite directions, there's no way to get them to "image" interactively at one location.